# Why do I get [object HTMLDivElement] on screen instead of the content while changing <div> content using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, innerhtml

I am trying to fetch title and body data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts and try to display these data on the screen. Only titles should be clickable. Here below is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="post">
            <a>
                <h3 class="title"> </h3>
            </a>
            <p class="body"> </p>
        </div>
        <script src="fetch.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

And here below is my javascript code.

```
const api_url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

async function getISS(){
   const response = await fetch(api_url);
   const data= await response.json();
   const { id, title, body } = data;

   document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = post;

   for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) { 
      post += `<a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${i}">
      <h3 class="title">${data[i].title}</h3></a>
      <p class="body">${data[i].body} </p>`;
   }
}  

getISS();
```

When I run this code, I get [object HTMLDivElement] on screen like this:[image: output picture]

I need to change divs content on javascript code. I am trying to do this using innerHTML. What am I doing wrong? I need to see the content instead of [object HTMLDivElement]. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried `${data[i].title.innerText}`? or `${data[i].title.innerHTML}`?

Answer (score 1):

A few things of note here:

1. Elements with an ID get an entry of that name in the global namespace. So, you `<div id="post"></div>` results in a global variable named `post`.
2. You don't declare a local variable `post` in your function, so it uses the global one pointing to the element.

   ```
   document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = post;
   ```

   Hence, this line is assigns the serialized (stringified) version of the global `post` (the one that points to the element) as your content, which is why you see `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

So how to fix?

Again two things:

1. Declare a local variable `post`.
2. Only set the content of your `<div>` **after** you assembled all content.

```
async function getISS(){
   const response = await fetch(api_url);
   const data = await response.json();

   let post = '';
   for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) { 
      post += `<a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${i}">
      <h3 class="title">${data[i].title}</h3></a>
      <p class="body">${data[i].body} </p>`;
   }

   document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = post;
}
```

or with a little more modern JS (assuming you actually want the first element of the result, which the above code ignores):

```
async function getISS(){
   const response = await fetch(api_url);
   const data = await response.json();

   document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = data
     .map( (el, ind) => `<a href="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${ind}">
      <h3 class="title">${el.title}</h3></a>
      <p class="body">${el.body} </p>` )
     .join( '\n' );
}
```